# where can I find mongodb documentation for _id.$oid?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

i tried looking through the javascript docs for mongodb, but come up empty:  http://api.mongodb.org/js/current/index.html

there doesn't seem to be any documentation for the datastore items returned....

is there somewhere else to look?

Comment: `_id.$oid` doesn't have any well known meaning in JavaScript.  Can you provide some context?  Are you maybe looking for the details of the ObjectId type?

Comment: it's something specific to mongodb,  or perhaps mongolab.com.    see my comment to dontGoPlastic's answer for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for it is [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/).

```
data_oid
{
  "$oid": "<id>"
}
```

Shell:

```
ObjectId( "<id>" )
```

Notes:

```
<id> is a 24-character hexadecimal string.
```

It's part of an extension for the [REST](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/) APIs. It an [ObjectId](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/object-id/), mapped to a structure that is intended to more closely represent the BSON ObjectId structure (as there's no equivalent in JavaScript for the ObjectID as it's a 12 byte number).

Answer (score 1):

Are you simply looking for information on what ObjectId is in mongodb?

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/object-id/

Comment: that's probably part of it, but specifically i'm trying to follow the example on the angularjs front page, where they obtain an object from: https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases

objects returned have properties like this._id.$oid  so i'd like to figure out what this $oid parameter is.    scattered in the mongodb docs i see vauge reference to oid, but no explicit definition of it.